# Hosting cloud service - general practice

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

These days i m trying my hands on windows azure, Its amazingly great.

My question is about cloud service deployment practice every time.

First time when i m setting up my cloud service env then I can deploy this using visual studio(taking long upto 30-40 min on my PC). later for any other code update into the site, I m just creating a new Package using vs(.cspkg and .cscfg files) and uploading directly on my service instance.

This is the general process of hosting cloud service. but every time uploading all file including static files is not a good way of hosting in general practice.

Is there any otherway to do the same thing. something like uploading precompiled dynamic pics with bin folder excluding other static content files. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

when it comes to static files, it is best to store them in Blobs. This allows you to update the blobs independently of your website. In addition, you can also leverage the CDN network using this approach, allowing you to cache your static content closer to your users for increased performance.

Here is further info on the Azure CDN: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/cdn/

Comment: Is this applied on all js/css and all default images used in project? And what should be the general hosting practice ?

Comment: Regarding js/css/images: this is not "automatic" - it is something you have to do yourself; then you application needs to load the files using their public URL so that your web app leverages CDN. Regarding general hosting, I suppose you could deploy your web site to multiple data centers and use a DNS provider (like the Windows Azure Traffic Manager) that routes users to the closest data center automatically for you. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh744833.aspx